# React Native - Images loading extremely slowly, not at all

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-ios

I am creating an app using Expo/RN where the first screen has a fair amount (~20) images loaded, as the result of a network call. I am only working in iOS.

My issue is that the images load extremely slowly, most taking around a minute to load, and some never load but stay black. I am using the built in Image component, with a url supplied in the source object. The images load immediately when the mobile website is loaded in Safari.

Furthermore, the built-in caching seems to not work at all. When an image has loaded and should be shown in multiple places, it often doesn't appear in the second place at all. I have tried using "force-cache" with no effect.

I have tried the packages react-native-fast-image, which wouldn't run, and react-native-expo-image-cache, which gave me some results but memory leak issues and UI freezes.

Is there any solution? Should I just create my own caching component?

EDIT: The images are loaded in a FlatList. Each item is rendered by a custom component including an . The image simply takes the url as

```
<Image
    style={[styles.image, smallCell ? { width: smallCellWidth } : {}]}
    source={{ uri: project.imageUrl, cache: "force-cache" }}
    opacity={0.85}
/>
```

Comment: Can I see the code that loads the image?

Comment: @hongdevelop added it, there's not a whole lot

Comment: You said you'd load 20 pieces. How do you load them?

Comment: @hongdevelop just using the built in Image component

Comment: Is it the same to get rid of the code to adjust the width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the biggest issue was not on the RN side, but the API call used. I was downloading the original sized images from the server, rather than the resized ones, and they were so large that I was getting the above result.

However, using force-cache did have good results for me.

Comment: Were you getting smaller images from the server or were you resizing them at download? If the latter, what did you use to resize network images? I can only find RN image manipulators that compress local images.

Comment: @cDub our server has a script that resizes images after they are uploaded, so I just had to select the correct image. Didn't do anything on the RN side.